# Apache POI - get pictures from single Sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm trying to load pictures from a single sheet however in [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images) there is only example how to load pictures from whole document (`workbook.getAllPictures();`)

Comment: why downvote? how is that unclear what I am asking for?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is something as simple as `getAllPictures()` available for individual sheets. One solution is to do something like this (this is assuming you're using XSSF):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = (XSSFSheet)wb.getSheetAt(0);

        //returns the existing SpreadsheetDrawingML from the sheet, or creates a new one
        XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet1.createDrawingPatriarch();

        //loop through all of the shapes in the drawing area
        for(XSSFShape shape : drawing.getShapes()){
            if(shape instanceof Picture){
                //convert the shape into a picture
                XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture)shape;

                //your logic here
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

The general idea is that we use `createDrawingPatriarch()` to retrieve the existing SpreadsheetML drawing from the sheet.

We can then use `getShapes()` to retrieve every shape contained in the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already started with the SS Common interface, you might want to have a solution which works in both APIs. Unfortunately the DrawingPatriach hasn't been fully SS-Commonized :(

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFShape;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Drawing;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Picture;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PictureData;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFShape;

public class XlsPictures {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("picture.xls"));
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Drawing draw = sh.createDrawingPatriarch();
        List<Picture> pics = new ArrayList<Picture>();
        if (draw instanceof HSSFPatriarch) {
            HSSFPatriarch hp = (HSSFPatriarch)draw;
            for (HSSFShape hs : hp.getChildren()) {
                if (hs instanceof Picture)  {
                    pics.add((Picture)hs);
                }
            }
        } else {
            XSSFDrawing xdraw = (XSSFDrawing)draw;
            for (XSSFShape xs : xdraw.getShapes()) {
                if (xs instanceof Picture) {
                    pics.add((Picture)xs);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Picture p : pics) {
            PictureData pd = p.getPictureData();
            byte saveme[] = pd.getData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to retrieve charts from excel using poi.
Because clearly getShapes() doesn't retrieve charts from a excel but only images!!

Comment: @KNDheeraj I haven't checked on how to process charts, but charts in Excel / Powerpoint every now and then popup in the mailing list. Your best bet is to either ask in the [user mailing list](http://poi.apache.org/help/index.html) or [search for similar questions](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=2280728&query=chart&i=12&sort=date) there ...